# Is there a tool that can convert common image formats (.bmp, jpg,..) to .emf files?

Tags: image

I'm using the GoDiagrams suite which seems to recommend .emf files for node images since they scale better on resizing. Bitmaps get all blurry.
Google doesn't show up any good tools that seem to do this... So to reiterate I'm looking for a image converter (preferably free) that converts an image (in one of the common formats like Bitmaps or JPEGs or GIFs) to an .EMF File.

*Update: I dont need to do it via code. Simple batch-conversion of images will do.*

Answer (score 2):

[Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) works well, it was recommended to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872/free-windows-based-emf-editor).

Answer (score 2):

Irfanview ([http://www.irfanview.com](http://www.irfanview.com/)) supports many image formats (including .emf). It's also small, fast, and very full-featured. It is free for non-commercial and educational use. I use it for all my image-conversion needs as it will work on batches of files and can rename them as it saves.

Answer (score 1):

[Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org) contains a tool called convert, that will convert from [just about anything](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) to EMF files. You can either use this as a separate application, or interface to it using [an API](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) that is available in several different languages.

Comment: ImageMagick didn't work for me. WinXP machine.
convert Back.JPG Back.emf => "convert: no encode delegate for this image format `Back.emf'." I tried the identify command, seems like it can only read emf files "EMF  WMF       r--   Windows WIN32 API rendered Enhanced Meta File"

Comment: ImageMagick supports EMF files only in READ mode, not WRITE.

Answer (score 1):

XnView (http://www.xnview.com). Very good viewer and converter.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ImageConverter Plus](http://www.imageconverterplus.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try http://autotrace.sourceforge.net/.  It is opensource and it has good results.  Download from here: http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=11789

Answer (score -1):

Really funny one Microsoft. Now this might seem outlandish but it works... (I have Visio2007). Just found this out from a colleague

You can drop a JPEG into **Microsoft Visio** (no less), Do a 'Save As' to .emf and voila! nice quality of a picture too.